# Problem with installing guest addtions on VirtualBox on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on Windows 11 , version 7.12 r159484 Qt5.15.2
I run in VirtualBox an Ubuntu server 22.04. I downloaded guest additions with command wget from VirtualBox on downloads.

VBOXGUestAdditions_7.0.0_BETA3.iso i mounted it into `/dev/cdro`m

Run the script but after reboot the same.

But I used `lsmod | grep -io vboxguest` and there is vboxguest

I checked it with command `imodinfo vbogxguest` and there is output:

```
filename: /lib/modules/5.15.0-89-generic/misc/vboxguest.ko
version: 7.0.0_BETA3 r153829
license: GPL
description: Oracle VM virtualbox guest additions for linux module
author: oracle and/or its affilliates
srcversion: 7FC6 (...)
alias: pci: (..)
depens:
retpoline: Y
name: vboxguest
vermagic: 5.15.0-89-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

but still VirtualBox Guest Addictions aren't working.